# SQL code (SSRS 2008 version)

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I need to write the following in SQL:

I have a table that has 2 columns that I am interested in (ID, Text field).  Each ID could have a few values in the text field.

```
ID   TEXT
1   value1
1   value2
2   value1
2   value2
2   value4
```

I need to create a report that list the following

```
ID     value1        value2       value3        value4         etc.  
1        yes          yes
2        yes          yes                        yes
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   Value1 = MAX(case WHEN [Text] = 'Value1' THEN 'yes' ELSE '' END),
   Value2 = MAX(case when [Text] = 'Value2' THEN 'yes' ELSE '' END),
   Value3 = MAX(case when [Text] = 'Value3' Then 'yes' ELSE '' END)
GROUP BY
   ID
```

Comment: @user1860212, if this answer was correct, could you please click the checkbox to the left of the answer to show that it is?  Thanks so much.